# Getting body of a message in a Twilio callback and using it in a response

Tags: twilio, twilio-api, wordpress-rest-api

From the TwiML Bin I found this reference to `{{body}}` and `{{from}}` but they don't work in TwiML as far as callbacks go. I'm having trouble getting the message details in the callback and I haven't been able to find suitable reference documenting it.

This is what I have (and this is confirmed working):

```
add_action( 'rest_api_init', 'register_receive_message_route');

/**
 * Register the receive message route.
 *
 */
function register_receive_message_route() {
  register_rest_route( 'srsms/v1', '/receive_sms', array(
    'methods' => 'POST',
    'callback' => 'trigger_receive_sms',
  ) );
}

/**
 * The Callback.
 *
 */
function trigger_receive_sms() {

  $y = "this works"; //$_POST['Body'], 0, 1592); << this doesn't

  echo ('<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>');
  echo ('<Response>');
  echo ("  <Message to='+NUMBER'>xxx $y xxx</Message>");
  echo ('</Response>');

  die();
}
```

What I'm missing is passing the body to the forwarded message. I have tried quite a few snippets at the end of the call back, but I'm really just guessing here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

When [Twilio makes a POST request to your URL](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/twiml/sms/twilio_request), it sends all the data about the SMS as URL encoded parameters in the body of the request. You can see all the parameters that are sent in the docs here: https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/twiml/sms/twilio_request#request-parameters.

When you receive a request to your WordPress URL, the callback function receives a `WP_REST_Request` object as an argument. This request object has access to all the parameters sent as part of the request and you can access them via array access using `$request['paramName']`.

So, to get the body of a message sent you need to call for `$request['Body']` like this:

```
function trigger_receive_sms($request) {
  $body = $request['Body'];

  // return TwiML
}
```

Let me know if that helps at all.

Comment: I am POSITIVE that is one of the ones I tried, I've been trying to find the example that I got it from, but I can't find it at the moment. I think I may have had a lower case `body`

Comment: It was in the example I left on [your last question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46059351/extending-twilio-plugin-to-work-with-wordpress-rest-api/46070176?noredirect=1#comment79150424_46070176). It is important that all Twilio parameters are sent capitalised, so `Body` will work but `body` won't.